# Is it possible to modify components from a shared view that is been used in a razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use a shared view composed of some buttons that are common throughout my app views. I use jquery to detect the button click using a class and not the id, since there may be more than one instance of the view. The script checks who is the parent form and everything works as expected.

There are times however, when it is necessary to change the caption of one or more buttons, or make one of them visible or not. I've an idea about how to it in jquery, but I was wondering if there is anyway to do it directly in the razor view.

```
// Shared View  "CommonBtnsGridTab"
    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs commonbtns-find"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;Find</button>
    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs commonbtns-all"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>&nbsp;All</button>
    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs commonbtns-view"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>&nbsp;View</button>
    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-info btn-xs commonbtns-new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;New</button>


 / / Razor view
           <div class="tab-pane" id="tabUnits">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="unitTab">
                            @Html.Partial("CommonBtnsGridTab")
```

Comment: Not unless you pass values indicating the `IsVisible` and `Caption` properties to the partial (using additional ViewData). Note its not necessary to include `id=""` in the buttons html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in the Razor view, the conditions that you want to act upon needs to be provided in the PartialView's Model ...So you use the passed in Model's property to construct the elements on the PartialView.